# How can I prevent my Edge driver from opening in private mode -Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a selenium script. I need the script to run in headless mode but it should do so using the normal Edge (not in private mode). The issue I am experiencing is it keeps opening it in private mode. Here is my script so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Edge in headless mode
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')  # Adjust to your desired size


# Initialize the Edge webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

# Navigate to the Power BI site
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/singleSignOn?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.powerbi.com%2F%3FnoSignUpCheck%3D1")
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to run in normal mode. Also just to add the reason I know it runs in private mode is due to my login credentials not being stored and also my organisation not allowing me to sign in to my Microsoft account in-private mode.